# Karate Report - Is there a way to generate karate/cucumber report before execution completes?

Tags: report, karate

I have a requirement where in I need to download couple of files (done using karate feature file) and move them to a specific folder (done using java and calling it in the feature file).

In between that I need to check if all the expected files are downloaded. So what I was thinking is, if there is a way to generate report before moving them to the specific folder. So from the report I can come to know if it has passed or failed.

I have the code for generating cucumber report in the runner class and i tried to use the below in the feature file and it does not run.. Gives an error

```
* def report = Java.type('BI.BiTestRunner')
* def result3 = report.generateReport()
```

Error:
BI.BiTestRunner failed due to: Arity error - expected: 1 actual: 0

Code in my runner class

```
package BI;

import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class BiTestRunner {

    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        System.setProperty("karate.env", "BI");
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:BI/Fluent.feature").outputCucumberJson(true).tags("~@ignore").parallel(1);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[]{"json"}, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "qa-automation");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me on this please?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. Until Karate completes, the files needed for `generateReport()` will not even exist.

This will require some advanced Java - and you can refer the section [in this guide](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#retry-framework-experimental) with the title "Retry Framework".

> With some custom Java code you should be able to take any failed tests at the end of a Runner invocation and re-try them, and merge the results back into the final aggregated report. See [example code](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-core/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/core/retry/RetryTest.java).

If the above does not help, please consider this as **not supported** by Karate.

Answer (score 0):

@Vishnuprya k I know this is a pretty old topic, but I managed to make the generateReport working as expected (generating Cucumber report before test method run ends).
Below is my code:

Test.class

```
public class AllTestsRunnerTest {

    @Test
    void testAll() {
        Results results = Karate.run().relativeTo(getClass()).tags("~@ignore").outputCucumberJson(true).parallel(1);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), "Expected failures");
    }

    public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
        Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] { "json" }, true);
        List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Your project name here");
        ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Functional / UI / API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Note:** In my feature files I do not have the *def report* and *def result3* directives set.

Hope this helps!